# When ReactDOM.render() is called within Angular1.x link step, does the state changes still matter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I am working an AngularectFrenkenstin, so I wonder does a call of `ReactDOM.render()` means a total replacement of everything within this component? Does state changes on the data set are still retained?

What is happening

```
return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        listings: '=',
      },
      link: (scope, iElem) => {
        scope.$watchCollection('listings', () => {
          ReactDOM.render(
            <ReactComponent1 listings={scope.listings} />, iElem[0]
          );
        });
      },
    };
```

So I assume when `listings` dataset is changed, rendering will just dump all the previous states. correct? or React is remembering only the change, even though angular is passing the whole thing into React again like what I showed in the example which shows a listing object got watched everything when its changed then it will call ReactDom.render().

What I learned:
[ReactDom.render() seems only fresh whats needed.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html)
However, angular digest is triggered when $watchCollection started ( I assume)?